# Spring Boot Testcontainers Gradle Multi-module Project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, testcontainers

I have a multi-module Spring Boot project and I’m attempting to use Testcontainers at development time following [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.testcontainers.at-development-time).

The problem I'm running into is when running the `main` method, gradle is complaining that it can't find the path to my sub-module.

The dependency looks as follows:

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(":libs:models")
  // more stuff here
}
```

My other unit tests are able to add the `models` project and test, it seems like when it's trying to run the `main` method, though, it's running into issues.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an IntelliJ issue more than anything.

I fixed by running a custom gradle task from the root project, and pointing `bootTestRun` at the correct application.